# What does the variable "window" represent in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking at some code for react native fetch blob https://github.com/joltup/react-native-fetch-blob and I see in their example to call `window.Blob`, etc..

Is Window a global variable like you would see in a browser web environment?  Or does it represent the current viewable screen in some way?  Is the below code example just replacing/overriding a global object?

```
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

React Native defines a few globals (all under `global`) that are polyfilled so certain libraries that were originally developed for the browser can be used without failing. Most of the polyfills for familiar browser APIs are empty. You can see them all in [`InitializeCore.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js).

`window` though is not empty. It's set to `global`:

```
if (global.window === undefined) {
  global.window = global;
}
```

So the next question is, what is `Blob` in `global`?

`Blob` is a property that is [added to `global`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js#L127) using the `polyfillGlobal` function. If you're curious about how that works, you can look at the [`PolyfillFunctions.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/PolyfillFunctions.js) file. `Blob` itself is defined in [`Blob.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Blob/Blob.js).

```
polyfillGlobal('Blob', () => require('Blob'));
```

So now that we see what React Native is doing, we can loop back to your questions:

- Is Window a global variable like you would see in a browser web environment?

  - Yes, it's a global variable that is a property of `global` that is set to equal `global`.
- Or does it represent the current viewable screen in some way?

  - Nope. It represents whatever React Native wants it to represent.
- Is the below code example just replacing/overriding a global object?

  - Yes. It's replacing `window.XMLHttpRequest` and `window.Blob` with react-native-fetch-blob's own implementation.

Comment: When I run code "window.Blob = Blob;"....I get error "window is not defined"

Comment: One of the best written answers I've seen on SO. Well done!